# If someone stole something before converting to Islam, what should they do with what they stole?

Tags: conversion, theft

Suppose someone stole something prior to converting to Islam. Further, suppose they are still in possession of the thing they stole. What should they do with the thing they stole?

The consensus seems to be that their pre-Islam sins are forgiven. However, this does not seem to grant ownership of the stolen object.

I'm not sure what would be the appropriate action here. If they try to return the object, they might get in trouble. Alternatives are throwing it away or giving it away.

Answer (score 2):

here's two things to consider.

firstly, the sin of stealing something, not the stolen object itself. When mentioned "all sins are forgiven", that includes this sin.

Then, the stolen object itself. The owner is and will be the owner as long as he don't handed over the ownership wilfully. So, the stolen object has to be returned as it was taken, or the demurrage that the owner agreed on. Otherwise, it will be avenged by Allah s.w.t. himself by taking good deeds from the thief, and giving it to the owner. If the thief don't have that much good deed, then bad deeds of the owner will be transferred to the thief.
That day every soul will have justice.

Comment: It would've been better if you'd included sources for second half of your answer.

Comment: inshaAllah, I will. Thanks for the reminder :)